# In WPF how do I bind a combobox to TabControl Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am learning WPF and I have a question about binding a ComboBox

I have a simple WPF window with the following controls: a ComboBox at the top, and a TabControl under it.

I populate the tabcontrol with two standard TabItems.  Then I add a few more tabs to it - however these are of my own "MyTab" class that simply inherits TabItem.  I'm not overriding anything or doing anything exotic, I just added a few public properties.

I want to use the ComboBox as a navigation tool.  Each tab has a header, and that same header should become an item in the ComboBox.  If selected out of the ComboBox, it should make that corresponding tab the active one.

Here is my setup on the ComboBox:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeListTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

.. and then further down in the Xaml ...

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Width="500" Name="qlist"
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tabControl1, Path=Items}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeListTemplate}" />
```

So I am just binding to the TabControl's Item collection and picking Header as the SelectedItem's property to display.

It works, and when I click the ComboBox, the headers are indeed displayed as individual text items.  But when I make an actual selection, that tab itself gets  rendered in the selection area of that combobox!

How do I fix this?  Why does it use the Header property for the list, but when I pick from the list, the value it displays becomes the actual TabItem object?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious

By the way, I know I said I want to use this to control navigation, but I stripped all of that out and I will worry about it after I figure out this maddening thing.

[image: Showing proper items in combobox]

Look carefully - when I pick tabItem1 from the combobox, it actually re-rendered that tab item inside the control.  You can see the top part of it, surrounded by the standard blue selection background a list item uses.  maddening.

[image: tabItem painting in combobox]

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any help

Comment: This is an actual bug in WPF. There is a solution to it, it is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546119/controlling-the-tabcontrol-active-tab-with-a-combobox

Comment: That is extremely helpful! Thank you! In the meantime, I redid this with a Listbox instead, and it works fine.  Including two-way binding, so I can select the active tab from either the tab control, or the list.  That was driving me nuts.  Thanks for giving me another reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way how WPF works. If the selected item can be rendered without DataTemplates, then it will be done so. Since Items collection is collection of VISUAL elements, then the DataTemplate wont be used to render the "selected" element.

Note to here: Selected item uses ContentPresenter, while the dropdown list uses another thing, called ItemsPresenter, which ALWAYS renders using DataTemplate, even if the underlying bound object can be rendered without one.

You need to bind your ComboBox&TabControl ItemsSource against your own custom list. This way yo will eventually get what you want. Alternatively you can just overwrite ComboBox complete visual tree(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - see the ContentPresenter part. Replace it with your datatemplate.

Comment: Sorry I have taken so long to mark this answered.  It took me a while to grasp all this, and you were/are indeed right.  It's been almost a year and I've learned a lot, I look back and this was a crucial moment in my learning.  I wound up just creating a wrapper class like you mentioned and bound to my own property that returned the visual.  That gave me the result I wanted